# I tried to use SMTP in python to send gmail, but it failed

Tags: email, smtplib

## here is my script:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
msg=MIMEText('hi, send by python.....','plain','utf-8')
from_addr='user@gmail.com'
passowrd='psw'
to_addr='user@gmail.com'
s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.login(from_addr,password)
s.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg.as_string())
```

## when it is running, error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\Desktop\begin.py", line 17, in <module>
s.login(from_addr, password)
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\smtplib.py", line 696, in login
"SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

## I try to fix it. I add code below:

```
...
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login(from_addr, password)
s.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

## here comes out error I really don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\Desktop\begin.py", line 20, in <module>
s.login(from_addr, password)
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\smtplib.py", line 729, in login
raise last_exception
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\smtplib.py", line 720, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File "C:\Users\bicuilin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvK\n5.7.14 1h8JVCjH3EdlnG4ye0St7PIWFsYfjtuO_qovrt6r-spvSMGNbeCxbpXuo3HfqK535dgJy2\n5.7.14 Tjz1zrEZI8QqRc0GyXD2t3Xa0rj_MVHbzX5fM1f2zgbFyoP9YUbwCyaRD5guosxyv3HcS8\n5.7.14 fvB_ORP6_djncJPUwGw98BDCTo2pw3RSvgYHAvS_xO-T97Hw2z35g3AKPW9Bb5E9EcpAgg\n5.7.14 pewpsm0VngKqoxhYhtFwHBW_8s1ig> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a67sm1686251qkc.24 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: In my mailer, gmail smtp port is set to 465

Comment: thanks for your advice, even though it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SMTP_SSL` class and it works (tested here). no need to `starttls` (won't work anyway)

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
msg=MIMEText('hi, send by python.....','plain','utf-8')
from_addr='user@gmail.com'
password='psw'
to_addr='user@gmail.com'
s=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
s.login(from_addr,password)
s.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score -1):

[Less Secure Apps - gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDAwH.png)

Had the same issue. after allow less secure apps at Gmail, got it working!

Comment: This could be better served as a comment, not an answer.